# Preencher Select com optiongroup

Tags: javascript, html, json

Pretendo criar um select multiplo igual esse

[image: Esse é o plugin multiple select]

O que consegui fazer foi este

[image: Esse foi o que fiz usando json para preencher dinamicamente]

O que pretendo é que  se agrupapam todos os registros do mesmo grupo, como esta organizado no plugin

[Veja o codigo aqui](http://jsfiddle.net/elonesampaio/4yy3xjyt/)

O meu json retorna isto [image: este array de objecto]

Comment: Olá Sam, nõ percebi bem qual é a parte que está a dar problemas. Tens um JSON e queres montar o `select` com esses dados? onde está a informação dos grupos no JSON? é o `nome1`?

Comment: sim o grupo é nome1. eu queria organizar por grupo(nome1).

Comment: Ok, podes dar-me esse JSON ou parte dele num jsFiddle para não ter de escrever à mão?

Comment: sim posso sim.            http://jsfiddle.net/elonesampaio/extbomx2/

Comment: Acho que colocaste o mesmo fiddle nos dois ^

Comment: desculpa ai, é esse aqui http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/multiple-select/docs/

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24072/discussion-between-sam-and-sergio).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A parte do AJAX tens de ser tu a fazer pois não posso testar, mas dentro do AJAX recebes um JSON já convertido em objeto. Aí, nessa função `done` podes usar assim:

```
var grupos = {};
json.forEach(function (data) {

    var grupo = data.nome1;
    if (!grupos[grupo]) {
        var optG = document.createElement('optgroup');
        optG.label = data.nome1;
        select.appendChild(optG);
        var g = {
            data: [],
            el: optG
        }
        grupos[grupo] = g;
        g.data.push(data);
    }
    var option = document.createElement('option');
    option.value = data.id;
    option.innerHTML = data.nome;
    grupos[grupo].el.appendChild(option);
});


$("select").multipleSelect({
    multiple: true,
    multipleWidth: 200,
    width: '100%'
});
```

O que esse código faz é criar um objeto ordenado por grupos. Á medida que vai criando/iterando esses elementos da array que recebes do servidor vai acrescentando conteúdo à página. Quando aparece um novo grupo (aqui: `if (!grupos[grupo]) {`) entõ ele cria novo `optgroup` e junta a `option` ali.

#### Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/cz89rtou/

Comment: Valeu! é mesmo isso que precisava. Obrigado